# why doesn't https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/myApp:myAction work?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, batch-file, facebook-fql

I created an action that also publishes an object.
I enabled publish_actions permissions.
I can get my list of actions via:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/myApp:myAction

but i can't get:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/myApp:myAction

Or do i need to just directly get a list of objects and somehow filter myself out?
I actually can't figure out how to get the object list without calling it through the associated action. Is that just how it is?

WORKAROUND:
First, I fql.query "select uid, name, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and is_app_user=1" and get back friends who have the app installed...

Second, 
I get back that query and use it to batch the following:

```
for (NSDictionary *d in friendsWithApp) {
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ \"method\": \"GET\", \"relative_url\": \"%@/myApp:myAction/myObject\" }", [d objectForKey:@"uid"]];
    jsonRequestsArray = [jsonRequestsArray stringByAppendingString:jsonRequest];

    setCount++;
    if (setCount!=[presets count]) {
        jsonRequestsArray = [jsonRequestsArray stringByAppendingString:@", "];
    }
}
jsonRequestsArray = [jsonRequestsArray stringByAppendingString:@" ]"];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonRequestsArray forKey:@"batch"];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Ugh. I also got a usable list with this fql.query:

"SELECT post_id, actor_id, attribution FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND app_id = MY_APP_ID"

But it doesn't return many items since it competes with the last 50 news items. Maybe it will be the way to go if the app is used enough, but it seems like use would drop off and then you couldn't get at the older posts easily.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) you can clearly see two additional permissions except for the "publish_actions" which you already have:

> user_actions:APP_NAMESPACE

and

> friends_actions:APP_NAMESPACE

and it states:

> Allows you retrieve the actions published by another application as
>   specified by the app namespace. For example, to request the ability to
>   retrieve the actions published by an app which has the namespace
>   awesomeapp, prompt the user for the users_actions:awesomeapp and/or
>   friends_actions:awesomeapp permissions.

Comment: This seems to let me have access to any installed apps publishing, but doesn't help me know what to call to read 'friends_actions' from within my own app. Any suggestions?

Comment: After you obtain the friends_actions:APP_NAMESPACE permission they should be accessible via /USER_ID_OF_FRIEND/APP_NAMSPACE:ACTION_NAME

Comment: this does work. i'm trying to get list of my custom actions performed by friends. not sure what best practice is, or if it's just not simple. I'd like to avoid iterating over my friends.

Comment: There's no connection to the "friends" connection of the User object. And so this: */me/friends/likes* won't work (even if you have the permissions), but *FRIENDID/likes* will work. I'd say that you should use FQL for that, but the info you are looking for is not accessible with FQL, at least not yet. You will need to iterate over the friends and check each one. You can how ever use the [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to speed things up.